# iterate through tr td elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following table

```
   <table id="myTable">
    <tbody>     
                    <tr role="row" class="odd">
                        <td>xx</td>                    
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>sss</td>
                        <td>00w</td>
                        <td>21</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>090</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>00:15</td>
                        <td>JHS</td>
                        <td>--</td>
           </tr>
           <tr> ... </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

on tr click I want to iterate trough each td and print their result to the console

```
 $('#myTablet body').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   ...
});
```

Comment: Do you mean iterate all `td` of clicked row or just all `td`?

Comment: table id you mention in jquery is wrong "myTable" ... please check

Comment: @user1765862, why do you vote the answers which were posted after my answer while my answer is correct ?

Comment: fixed, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to `iterate` all `tr` elements and display every `td` cell from `tr`.This can be achieved by using `each()` method.

> `find()` method get the descendants of each element in the current set
>   of matched elements

```js
$('#myTable tbody tr').on('click', function () {
   $(this).find('td').each(function(index,item){
       console.log($(item).html());
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>     
           <tr role="row" class="odd">
             <td>xx</td>                    
             <td>100</td>
             <td>sss</td>
             <td>00w</td>
             <td>21</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>090</td>
             <td>12</td>
             <td>00:15</td>
             <td>JHS</td>
             <td>--</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>xx</td>                    
             <td>100</td>
             <td>sss</td>
             <td>00w</td>
             <td>21</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>090</td>
             <td>12</td>
             <td>00:15</td>
             <td>JHS</td>
             <td>--</td>
           </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTablet tr.row').on('click', function (e) {
       $(this).find('td').each(function(index, element) {
            console.log($(element).text();
       }
       )
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following. First click a tr and get all its tds, then iterate.

```
$('#myTable tr').on('click', function (e) {
   var tds = $(this).find("td");
   tds.each(function(){
       console.log($(this).text());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
$(document).on("click",'tr', function(){
   $(this).find("td").each(function(x,y){
      console.log($(this).html());
   });
});
```

Give it a try. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use the [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function:

```
$('#myTablet tr').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(e.currentTarget).find('td').each(function(i,e) {
        console.info($(e).text();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this Example

```js
$(function() {
   $(document).on('click', '#myTable', function (e) {
     $("#tr_row").clone().appendTo("#dynamic");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>     
       <tr role="row" class="odd" id="tr_row">
          <td>xx</td>                    
           <td>100</td>
           <td>sss</td>
           <td>00w</td>
           <td>21</td>
           <td>2</td>
           <td>090</td>
           <td>12</td>
           <td>00:15</td>
           <td>JHS</td>
           <td>--</td>
         </tr>
         <span id="dynamic"></span>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```